# If the role of Indra and other devas will be held by another man in next Kalpa, what will happen to current ones?

Tags: gods, kalpa

Isn't Indra and other devas immortal? They drank Amrut so, they have to survive forever, and in next Kalpa, new devas and new Indra will come so then what will happen to previous ones?

Comment: They dissolve into paramatma and if not attained moksha they’ll take rebirth and possibly become devatas again of that kalpa

Comment: How can they take rebirth, they are immortal! They dissolve into Parmatma, by their bodies drank Amrit!